# TFS: Can I throttle Visual Studio somehow to avoid: HTTP 500 The number of requests per minute exceeded the configured limit

Tags: visual-studio

We have a third party developer housing our source code on their TFS server. I am in the process of downloading the entire 1.5gb and progress is frequently halted with this error:

> HTTP code 500: ( The number of HTTP requests per minute exceeded the
>   configured limit. Contact the server administrator. )

Visual Studio maintains the connection and continues to retry. The next few requests fail with this error:

> TF400324 Team Foundation services are not available from server xxx.xxxxxx.net.
>   The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a send.

After a while, the throttle is removed and download resumes full-speed until I hit the threshold again.

**The third party is unwilling to alter their configuration. Is there something I can do in Visual Studio (2017) or on my PC to slow down the requests so I don't hit their limit?**

Comment: If you don't get entire sources, but part of them, will you get this message?

Comment: Yes. The error does not seem to be related to the size of the download, it is the speed of the requests.

Comment: It seems your issue is not related to TFS, but the network download speed, correct?

Comment: The error message does not come from TFS. Did you use proxy in your network?